# Page Loading time - Compare results after performance changes

Tags: javascript, performance

I am about to make some changes in my site in the area of loading time.
For example minimize the HTTP requests, minify contents and more.

How can I actually measure the changes and understand what change had the biggest impact on my site and also  have a report of the improvement time.

From my point of view, checking the results in my real site is not a good idea because of external network "Noises", How can I clean my environment from noises and measure the changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Boomerang](http://yahoo.github.com/boomerang/doc/) - you can use it to test user's real page load speeds.

Comment: this is not what i asked, but this is exactly what i need.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of online services that help you understand your page load times as well as offer tips on how to minimize it. Such as minifying CSS/JS, using a CDN etc.

- http://www.webpagetest.org/
- http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/
- http://tools.pingdom.com/